# how to create a selection group in edit mode?

Tags: modeling

it is pretty annoying to work with different meshes as the same object.

Is there any way I can define a specific numbers of vertex/edges/faces to a group so I could just click that group to all?

I hope I was clear

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can define [vertex groups](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/vertex_groups/vertex_groups.html?highlight=vertex%20groups) per object:

[image]

1. In Edit Mode move to *Properties Editor > Data > Vertex Groups*
2. Hit the <kbd>+</kbd> sign to create a new vertex group (and rename it to something useful)
3. Make a selection and <kbd>Assign</kbd> the desired vertices to that group

Now by using <kbd>Select</kbd> the vertices will automatically selected in the 3d viewport.