# Is there a "reselect" option in Blender?

Tags: edit-mode

I am very new to Blender & can't find a "reselect" option in any menu. I also need "undo" & "redo" please.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by reselect? Selecting again something that was previously selected but now has become unselected? If that's what you mean, what does that do, that undo doesn't do?

Comment: The Undo Stack generally takes into account selection operations, so if if select or de-select something and then undo or redo it should "reselect"

Comment: To save a selection of vertices you can create a **[vertex group](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/assigning_vertex_group.html)**, and assign the vertices to it. Then you can simply re-select the group again anytime you need. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/35029/1853

Answer (score 3):

"In Blender, in edit and object mode, anyway, the key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> is "undo"; the key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHFT</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> is "redo". The undo history is accessed by the key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>, listing the number of actions as defined by the user in the user preferences under the "Editing" tab, under the heading "Global Undo".

Additionally, <kbd>SHFT</kbd>-R repeats the last action.

Comment: And for those looking for menu items, the undo/redo is found in the Object or Edit menu at the bottom of the 3d view - not at the top of the window where most people will first look.

Comment: Thanks to all who replied. As I said I am very new to this & the "undo" option wasn't covered in the basic tutorial.